In Dagster, how can I iterate over a function to allow for parallelization with DynamicOutputs
I have been trying to find the solution but I am not sure how to word this, my script is structured like the below. The goal is instead of having 3 nearly identical ops, I can have one but still parallelize them. The real life version has the funcrun function read from a db with millions of rows, each iteration pulls certain values based on the input from the list. The ilistval is used to index said list. However, this errors with DagsterInvarientViolationError: Attempted to iterate over an InvokedNodeOutputHandle.
I tried to used a map such that ilistvals.map(lambda i: funcrun(i, xlt)) but that also didn't work.
Is this something possible at all or am I better off just having 3 identical ops seperated out?
from dagster import job, op, DynamicOutput, DynamicOut, Output
import pandas as pd

@op()
def funcrun(ilistval, sedint):
    result = df ... #result is a dataframe
    return DynamicOutput(result, mapping_key=str(ilistval))

@op()
def rainlist():
    dfrt=pd.read_csv("file.csv")
    xlist=(dfrt.head(3))[a]
    return xlist

@op()
def aristo():
    dfrt=pd.read_csv("file.csv")
    return dfrt

@op()
def generate_ilistvals():
    for ilistval in range(3):  # Generate values 0, 1, 2
        yield DynamicOutput(ilistval, mapping_key=str(ilistval))

@op
def process_results(dfrt,r1,r2,r3):
    wrt=pd.concat(r1,r2,r3)
    ... joining with dfrt....
    return wrt2

@job(name="fyzd")
def jobrunner():
    orig = aristo()
    xlt=rainlist() 
    ilistvals = generate_ilistvals() 

    results = []
    for ilistval in ilistvals:
        results.append(funcrun(ilistval, xlt))
    
    process_results(orig, *results)

